# Does this smell of a DB error?

Tags: oracle

I have Cisco prime Infrastructure on a closed network and I have a problem.
I have about 3000 units to manage, and when my server has been online for about 20 mins, I cant delete any unit from my gui. I can add units with no proplem. After 3-4 days, the server i very slow in respons.
If I reload the server I can delete units again, and about 20 mins later I cant again.
The server has 128 GB Ram and a HP G10 server with all cpu dedicated to this one program.
If I keep the units under 800, I dont have the problem.
I can reproduse the error on other hardware platforms.
I have No idea where to start, and TAC is no go.

Brian

Comment: "All CPUs dedicated to this one program" is that for both DB and Mid Tier?

Comment: I must say, you are not talking to a DB Guy  when I say all cpu, I mean in wmvare, all the power goes to Cisco prime, no other aplications. Prime is just installed with higest amount possible.

Comment: Probably something very basic like a row lock (from your application updating something and not committing). Could be a piece of application SQL which sometimes chooses a different execution plan. Get your DBA to have a look to see what is going on. If you have an actual error message then give it a google (and consult with your DBA). Ultimately, you need someone to look at the DB.

Comment: Typically, if a third party application stops working as expected, one contacts the said third party technical support, for which one pays, and demands answers. Is there a reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: The reason for saying No TAC is becsuse the system is on closed network and I can not deliever any data from it to Them to investegate.

Comment: Andrew thx, I will do that 